# Highcharts - export to base64 using allow html?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, highcharts

This the code that I use for the base64 conversation on the local browser

```
 var render_width = chart.plotWidth;
 var render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth;

 // Get the chart's SVG code
 var svg = chart.getSVG({
     exporting: {
         sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
         sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
     }
 });

 // Create a canvas
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.id = "render";
 canvas.height = render_height;
 canvas.width = render_width;
 //canvas.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
 //canvas.style = "display:hidden";
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);



 var dogImage = new Image;
 //dogImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

 dogImage.onload = function() {
     if (chart.plotWidth < chart.plotHeight) {
         plot = chart.plotWidth;
     } else {
         plot = chart.plotHeight;
     }
     f = 0.65;
     var imageHeight = plot * f;
     var imageWidth = plot * f;

     var textX = (chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth * 0.5)) - (imageHeight / 2);
     var textY = (chart.plotTop + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5)) - (imageWidth / 2);

     canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, textX, textY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

     // Create an image and draw the SVG onto the canvas
     var image = new Image;
     //image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
     image.onload = function() {
         canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, chart.plotLeft, 0, render_width, render_height);

         var d = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

         //var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
         var data = {
             chart_image: d,
             animal_id: animal_id
         };
         asyncRequest.postData(url, data, function(data) {
             //console.log(data);
             $("#loading-modal").addClass('display-none');
             location.href = data.file_path;
         });
         //$('body').append("<img src='"+d+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
         document.body.removeChild(canvas);
     };

     image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svg);
 };

 dogImage.src = center_image;
```

This is working only if the **allowHTMl is false** inside the high charts options

```
exporting: {
                      // allowHTML: true,
                    buttons: {
                        exportButton: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        printButton: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        contextButton: {
                            enabled: false
                        }

                    }
                },
```

is there a way that I can export the base64 with the allowHTML option. If the allowHTML is true and then it will send me back with a base64 that i cant use as an image src.This is for a Custom DOMPDF

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue so that it works even if `allowHTML` is disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/k5m2zr6f/ Please provide some live working demo (minified example preferable) of your problem and a detailed description what's happening in the code.